# Ponerle un value por defecto a un Input type Date

Tags: php, html, html5, date

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto utilizando HTML5 y PHP, en este proyecto tengo la opción de registrar personas, en el cual se le piden datos generales como nombres, apellidos, fecha de nacimiento, etc.

Para la fecha de nacimiento utilicé un ***input type Date*** para que me desplegara un calendario en el formulario, sí funciona. Ahora bien, tengo otro formulario en el cual se puede actualizar la información de la persona que se ha registrado, en ese formulario se cargan todos los datos anteriormente ingresados y se colocan en los `textbox` de manera automática, pero quiero que en el ***input type date*** salga automáticamente la fecha que se registró, sin tener que ponerla de nuevo.

Les dejo aquí mi código PHP

```
<?php require ('conexion.php'); if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
  /*echo "FUNCIONA;*/

  $id = $_GET["id"];
  $stmt = $mbd- prepare("CALL sp_getdataupdate(?)");
  $stmt- bindparam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt- execute();
  $result = $stmt- fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $stmt = null;    /* $fecha = $result['fecha_nacimiento'];
  $fecha1 = split("/",$fecha);
  $fechaf = $fecha1[0]."-".$fecha1[1]."-".$fecha1[2];
  //$fechaf;
  //var_dump($result); */ }

  if(isset($_POST["actualizar"])) {
    /*echo "FUNCIONA;*/
    $stmt = null;

    $curp = $_POST["curp"];
    $nombres = $_POST["nombres"];
    $apellido_paterno  = $_POST["apellidop"];
    $apellido_materno = $_POST["apellidom"];
    $fecha_nacimiento = $_POST["nacimiento"];
    $sexo = $_POST["sexo"];
    $calle = $_POST["calle"];
    $numero_exterior = $_POST["numex"];
    $numero_interior = $_POST["numint"];
    $codigo_postal = $_POST["cp"];
    $colonia = $_POST["colonia"];
    $estatus = $_POST["estatus"];
    $delegacion = $_POST["delegacion"];
    $id = $_POST["id"]; 

    $stmt = $mbd- prepare("CALL sp_actualizarregistros(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt- bindparam(1, $curp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(2, $nombres, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(3, $apellido_paterno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(4, $apellido_materno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(5, $fecha_nacimiento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(6, $sexo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(7, $calle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(8, $numero_exterior, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(9, $numero_interior, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(10, $codigo_postal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(11, $colonia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(12, $estatus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(13, $delegacion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt- bindparam(14, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt- execute();
    $result = $stmt- fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($result);

    if (isset($result["Mensaje"])) {
      echo "ERROR AL REGISTRAR!";
    }
    else {
      echo "CORRECTO";
    } } ?>
```

Comment: Hola Emanuel, **es importante que leas [ask]** debes colocar el código que estas usando para tratar de mostrar la fecha en tu input, debes decir si te han salido errores, como estas devolviendo los datos? Toda esa información es importante para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida en la comunidad !

Answer (score 2):

Para colocarle un valor por defecto a un input type date, este debe estar en formato YYYY-mm-dd, luego cuando cargas datos desde tu base de datos mediante php la fecha puede venir desordenada y con "/" en lugar de "-", para eso puedes colocar tu input de la siguiente forma:

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($valor['fecha'])) ?>">
```

En caso de que estes utlizando una clase para generar un calendario con js o jquery (como datepicker), deberas cambiar el 'Y-m-d' por el formato que necesitas, por ejemplo:
si es '01/01/2000' el formato sera 'd/m/Y',
si es '01-01-99' el formato sera 'd-m-y', etc.
Si tu calendario require tambien la hora como '01/01/2000 01:00:00', el formato será: 'd/m/Y H:i:s', donde la H es para la hora, i para minutos y s para segundos.
Espero sea de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías utilizar:

```
<input type="date" value="2017-11-31">
```

En el value cargar con php la fecha de registro, supongo que al registrarse la habrás guardado en una base de datos, no?

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo $valor_database; ?>">
```

Comment: Si los tengo en base de datos, por $valor_database te refieres a la variable que cree para la fecha?

Comment: Exacto, y en formato YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: $fecha_nacimiento es la variable que he creado, entonces al momento de ponerla  <input type="date" name="nacimiento" class="input-100" value="<?php echo $result [$fecha_nacimiento]; ?>"> no me pinta nada en el Input Type Text

Comment: Prueba con esto: <?php date('y-m-d', strtotime($result["fecha_nacimiento"]));?>

Comment: Sigue sin pintarme la fecha que ingrese en el registro, aunque en el DATE al momento de correrlo en el navegador me aparece el formato : dd/mm/aaaa pero lo checo en la base de datos y sale en formato YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Falta el `echo` mis amigos: `<input name="nacimiento" type="date"
value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($result["fecha_nacimiento"])) ?>"/>` Suponiendo que `$result` sea tu conjunto de resultados. O si tienes la fecha en una variable, mejor, más claro: `$fecha=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($result["fecha_nacimiento"]));` Y en el input:  `<input name="nacimiento" type="date"
value="<?php echo $fecha ?>"/>` A mi no me gusta esa horrible mezcla de HTML con PHP, yo concatenaría todo en código PHP y al final haría `echo` de mi input.